# Cookie e compartilhamento entre subdomínios?

Tags: cookies

Tenho um site com o seguinte endereço `http://www.mysite.com.br` que na programação [back-end](/questions/tagged/back-end) é criado alguns [cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) de configurações e até de informações com dados criptografado. Agora foi criado um subdomínio com o seguinte endereço `http://api.mysite.com.br` para um novo site e acabei percebendo que existe o compartilhamento dos mesmos cookie e até acesso as chaves criadas onde as aplicações rodam no mesmo servidor.

***Pergunto:***

---

1. Há realmente o compartilhamento de [cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) entre aplicação e seus subdomínios?
2. Quais os pontos positivos?
3. Quais os pontos negativos?
4. De um modo geral existe algum técnica melhor para compartilhamento de informações do domínio para subdomínios

Comment: Dois votos negativos? tem algum problema porque ultimamente só levo votos negativos?

Comment: Estou passando pela mesma coisa. Estou achando que é um autômato negativando certos usuários usando várias contas para burlar a detecção de fraude do sistema, pois os negativos que estou recebendo estão ocorrendo com certa periodicidade.

Comment: Eu vi as suas reclamações @AugustoVasques e tem muita relevância o que acaba de comentar, eu não sei mais o que fazer parece totalmente perseguição.

Comment: Eu o entendo a sua angustia. Pois mesmo sendo uma atividade não remunerada e de participação não obrigatória eu contribuo com o meu melhor em cada uma de minhas publicações. Nas publicações de terceiros faço o possível para deixar um feedback sobre o porque dum down vote ou fechamento. Sempre quando realmente há algum problema com uma de minhas publicações a comunidade **sempre** negativou apontando onde estava minha falha. Agora receber um negativo em algo que está correto e de acordo com normas de publicação do site e sem explicações é constrangedor.

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo da aplicação pode ser um problema compartilhar cookies entre diferentes subdomínios, inclusive porque você informou que os cookies contém até dados criptografados.
Eu criaria uma tabla no BD e colocaria nela os seguintes campos:

1. Cookie de sessão (Ex: PHPSESSID)
2. Subdomínios onde os dados serão visíveis.
3. Os dados criptografados.

Dessa forma, você pode criar um método que verifica o cookie de sessão, o subdomínio atual do usuário e confere no BD se ele tem acesso aos dados criptografados. Isso protegeria os dados criptografados e só os liberaria caso o cookie de sessão casasse com o subdomínio.
Outra alternativa pode ser aproveitar a flexibilidade dos sessionStorage(), mas também não são tão seguras quanto essa técnica do BD.

Answer (score -1):

1. Sim, há compartilhamento se o domínio for especificado ao gerar o cookie. Por exemplo, se for especificado o domínio como "mysite.com", incluirá todos os subdomínios ("api.mysite.com"). Se não for especificado, o padrão é a parte do host local do documento atual, ou seja, deve corresponder exatamente ao domínio do cookie ("host-only cookie").
2. Um ponto positivo é que você pode compartilhar um mesmo cookie entre seus domínios. Imagine vários sistemas em projetos separados, você pode, por exemplo, usar o cookie para fazer autenticação entre eles, dispensando as várias telas de login.
3. Não vejo ponto negativo, já que é possível limitar o cookie apenas ao host local como explicado no item 1.
4. Isso depende de qual tipo de informação deseja trafegar entre os domínios. Dependendo do que precisa, você pode até mesmo fazer uso do banco de dados. Mas cookies funcionam bem para o exemplo que você informou.

Comment: Qual é o problema da resposta? tem alguma indicação de problema relate e outra coisa quem negativou pode adicionar uma resposta melhor indicando os problemas das outras respostas?

Comment: Pois é, também não entendi. Poderia ao menos acrescentar alguma informação à resposta.